# Model to use when the response is numeric and predictors are ordinal

Tags: regression, model, biostatistics

I have a dataset of Clinical values for BP, Blood Sugar levels, Height, Weight, and so on. I have categorized these variables based on standard guidelines like WHO (into Clinical Risk Levels). Examples of Clinical Risk Levels are Stage-1 Hypertension, Stage-2 Hypertension, etc (for the clinical variable 'BP'). I have computed some Wellness Scores based on the Clinical Risk Levels.

So, it flows like this:

Clinical Values → Clinical Risk Factors → Response Variable

The Clinical Values are Numeric in nature. The Clinical Risk Factors are Ordinal in nature (High, Normal, Low, etc for each Clinical Value), and the Response variables are Ordinal in nature too. I am struck with building a model. My first query is:

1. Which variables do I consider as my predictors? The Clinical Values or the Clinical Risk Factors? I have arrived at my Scores based on the Clinical Risk Factors. So, is it still possible for me to consider my Clinical Values as predictors?
2. What algorithm should I use when

   (a) my parameters are numeric and Response is numeric

   (b) my parameters are ordinal and Response is also numeric

As for 2 (b), if I have to use Multiple Linear Regression, I am not sure if I am using the right model. This is because I cannot exactly say that the predictors are linear w.r.t the response. But, the fact is, my scoring is based on whether each Clinical Risk Factor is High/Normal/Low. So, could I assume that they share a linear relationship?

Comment: Why did you categorize the numerical predictors? That is loosing information.